# Is a command a sort of event handler or why does my button execute the command?

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I'm learning about wpf, delegates, event and I have some clue on what does what, but I'm a little lost when it comes to implementing `ICommand`

I have a class the implements the `ICommand` interface like this

```
class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> _execute;
    private Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this (execute, null)
    {

    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object,bool> canExecute)
    {
        this._execute = execute;
        this._canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        this._execute(parameter);
    }

    public void OnCanExecute()
    {
        if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
        {
            CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
```

And then my ViewModel that uses i.

```
class PersonViewModel
{
    public ICommand ICommandPresenter { get; set; }
    public PersonModel PM;
    private string _btnString = "";

    #region Propertys
    public string ButtonString
    {
        get {return _btnString; }
        set
        {
            if (_btnString.Equals(value))
            {
                return;
            }

            _btnString = value;
        }
    }
    public string Name { get { return PM.Name; } set
        {
            PM.Name = value;
        }
     }
    #endregion Propertys
    public PersonViewModel()
    {
        PM = new PersonModel();
        ICommandPresenter = new RelayCommand(ChangeName);
    }

    public void ChangeName(object a)
    {
        string s = a as string;
        MessageBox.Show("Hello from PersonViewModel Commander: " + s);
    }
}
```

This is where it gets confusing for me. In the `RelayCommand` class I have an event `CanExecuteChanged` but that event is never executed/fired. From what I've understood from my reading on events is that you don't "need" to have subscribers to an event, but if you're going to have an event you should atleast have somewhere in the code that executes it. But I don't have that in my code but for some reason my button still does what I command it to do. I still understand that I've clicked the button but I don't have anything in my code that is subscribed to that button.

- **Why is my button able to execute my code even though I don't have an event connected to it?**
- **Since I don't have any subscribers connected to `CanExecuteChanged` event does it becomes useless?**
- **Is the command acting like an event? if so, please describe the whole process from clicking the button to executing the command.**

Answer (score 0):

CanExecuteChanged is member of ICommand class and, simplifying the things, is used by wpf framework to enable/disable your button depending on result of CanExecute() method. CanExecute is not tight to the code you want to execute when you click the button, but to the condition, when it's legal to be done.

Command executes your code, because you send *pointer to your method(ChangeName method)* here:

> `ICommandPresenter = new RelayCommand(ChangeName);`

So you are not using `CanExecuteChange` at all, because you are invoking this constructor:

> `public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)`.

To have CanExecute you have to invoke overloaded constructor that accepts CanExecute predicate:

> `public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object,bool> canExecute)`

And to invoke it just pass some function that returns a bool as second parameter:

`ICommandPresenter = new RelayCommand(ChangeName, ()=>MyCustomLogicWhenButtonIsActive());`

Comment: Yeah I understand that but my question (Maybe I stated it badly) is more about the button. Example to be able to have a button fire an event would be like this `<Button OnClick="My_function">` and this explains as `Button.Event += new NameOfEventHandler(My_function)`. Is this what command is doing to my button?

Comment: If you will use OnClick event, then you will be restricted to indicate My_Function inside code-behind xaml.cs file. Having business logic there is a bad practice because you get it mixed with UI presentation logic. When you are working with ICommands that implies you are using MVVM, so all business logic is isolated in ViewModel. Connection is made via bindings. So your code will look like <Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>

Comment: Command is not doing anything with your button. There is some WPF "magic" that internally on button click checks if there is a command associated with the button being clicked and if so, then calls the command.

Comment: Is there someway to understand this "magic" ? Cause I think that is what makes it problematic for me to understand how it works. Cause it doesn't make sense to with the `public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this._execute(parameter);
    }`. I understand that it's a delegate but is the button invoking the `Action` when clicked? And why would you need the button to have `CanExecute = false`?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I saw in .Net's source code, the command assigned to the button's `Command` property is executed in the following way:

1. Clicking the button calls the button's `OnClick()` method (located in the button's `ButtonBase` base class).
2. The `OnClick()` method ([see source here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Primitives/ButtonBase.cs,c0949dd81fca07f3)) calls the `Commands.CommandHelpers.ExecuteCommandSource()` method, passing `this` as the command source parameter.
3. The `ExecuteCommandSource()` ([see source here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/MS/Internal/Commands/CommandHelpers.cs,21ab53ee75734350,references)) further calls the `CriticalExecuteCommandSource()` method, passing the same command source as a parameter.
4. Finally, the `CriticalExecuteCommandSource()` method ([see source here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/MS/Internal/Commands/CommandHelpers.cs,af615bcf72cb6ed8)) accesses the command source's `Command` member, and:

   - checks if the command's `CanExecute()` method returns `true`,
   - if it's `true`, it calls the command's `Execute()` method.
5. *(If you use a `RelayCommand` implementation, then obviously, the `RelayCommand` class relays the call to the specific method you passed to its constructor when you instantiated it.)*

---

So, to answer your question whether commands are fired through an event:

**The source indicates that the `OnClick()` method executes the command directly, not through event handling. As you can see in the source, this method *does* raise the `Click` event, but it does so separately from the command execution.**

*Though, it remains unanswered how the `OnClick()` method is being called in the first place by the framework; I have no idea about that.*